# Bukkit plugin error when starting

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've just started Java today. I'm trying to make a basic test Plugin for a Minecraft Server that when the user types `/Hello` it gives a response message.

However, I get this error when I launch the server. The only thing I understand is it's a source issue, might this be a problem with my import statements? I added the imports directly from the Bukkit website and directly from the same Java file the server uses.

The command I made isn't recognized in Game and the log output I made that should say `Plugin has started` doesn't work either.

Here's a link to the plugin jar: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sphm1gww1fmmx3/Law%27s%20Plugin.jar?dl=0

Here's the error I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: Please post relevant code so we don't have to click links.

Comment: Please watch the language and include relevant code in the question.

Comment: The answer is in the error, "name ... contains invalid characters", could be the apostrophe or the space, either way, try removing both and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is right there in the error message:

```
org.bukkit.InvalidDescriptionException: name 'Lawrence's Plugin' contains invalid characters.
```

This means that in your `plugin.yml` your `description` attribute has a character that Bukkit didn't know how to handle.  In general, if you have an `invalid character` error, it's usually a symbol (E.g. \ % $ / ' " etc.).

My guess, in this case, is it's the `'` in the description`Lawrence's Plugin`, try removing it and see if that works!

Comment: That actually fixed it. Thanks! From the tutorials I watched, I was under the impression the plugin.yml didn't adhear to standard code format, I thought everything inside it was like a giant string.

Comment: Nope!  Truthfully `plugin.yml`s are a pain, and usually, cause quite a bit of annoyance.  But when you have trouble, refer to the [plugin.yml documentation](http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_YAML).  Also, remember to Upvote/Accept answers that you find helpful ;)